# Suppose you hear a commandment how do you know it’s God and not your own mind, or Satan?

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, nevua-prophecy

Considering God asked Abraham to kill his son, it seems difficult to differentiate the word of God from that of Satan, how is one to know from whom a commandment is given?

Is there a way to discriminate the word of God from an imposter, an angel, a hallucination?

Suppose you follow Gods commandment and it turns out to be an imposter, will you be punished by God?

Comment: As I recall the Rambam writes in the Moreh Nevuchim that a navi knows without a doubt that the communication is from Hashem (this clarity is part of the nevuah) so if one had doubts then it would falsify the "nevuah"....although it seems to me that a number of examples in the T'nakh describe nevuah with no such clarity.  And how such certainty is any different from the mentally ill, or perhaps extreme ideologues, who could experience certainty of their beliefs as well.

Comment: Is this question different in that it assumes God could speak to non prophets?

Comment: Yeah asking regarding regular people, can understand if there is some overlap